# Pattern for returning results based on multiple parameters

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am working on legacy code where a method is supposed to return results based on mulitple parameters. The pattern used in code works but I'm thinking if it could be improved further. I'll give an example

Let's say I have a class JobPosting which has various properties

```
class JobPosting {
    int jobPostingId;
    String description;
    Dept dept; // A posting ca belong to 1 department at a time
    Location loc; // A job posting can belong to 1 location at a time
    String created By;
    int headcount; // number of people required to fill the job posting
    List<User> assignedUsers; // number  of people who have applied for the posting already
    List<User> reservedUsers; // users who are eligible to apply for the posting, if this is empty, then anyone can apply to posting
    DateTime visibleDate; // date from when posting is visible to users
    Date endDate; // posting's deadline
    ...
}
```

These details for a posting is stored in DB in one table

Now I have various use cases to get the postings:

```
- Get job postings for a loc & dept- I only care about description and headcount.
- Get job posintgs for a loc & dept with users who have filled the postings
- Get job postings for a loc & dept with users who have filled and users who are eligible for the postings
- Get job postings for a loc & dept which are visibleToUsers (visibleDate < curdate)
```

and so on, I can have various possibilities for getting the postings depending on the scenario.

Current implementation is that we have builder pattern for parameters

```
class postingsParams {
    boolean excludeFilledPostings;
    boolean excludeNonVisiblePostings;
    boolean returnAssignedUsers;
    boolean returnEligibleUsers;
}
```

and one method which takes in parameters and determines what fields in JobPostings to fill and what postings to exclude

```
getPostingsByLocDept(loc, dept, postingsParamas) { ...// code calls dynamic SQL queries to return results and if conditions to filter }
```

This seems to work fine, but what I don't like is

```
- Each caller must be aware of all the possible crtireia to search
- If in future I want to add another criteria like excludePostingsWithPassedDeadline, I need to make changes to this method and need to test all the places where it is called to make sure nothing breaks
```

One approach is to create specific get methods for the use case, but with that approach we may end up with multiple get methods, which may not be desirable.

Is there a way to improve this design or is the current approach best way to deal with this kind of scenario?

Comment: I suggest this question is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, provided that some working code is added.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to work with JPA, using a spring implementation (e.g. with the dependency org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.7.2.RELEASE).

Then you just define interfaces extending CrudRepository, like:

```
public interface MyEntityRepo extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long>
{
    public Collection<MyEntity> findByAccountIdAndProductId( 
                                                       Long aAccountId, 
                                                       Long aProductId );

    MyEntity findByDeviceHwIdAndLicenseLicenseLicenseeName( String aHwId, String aLicenseeName );

    etc.
```

where MyEntity is a annotated POJO bean like:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "my_entity" )
public class MyEntity implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = IDENTITY )
    @Column( name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false )
    private Long Id;

    @Column( name = "account_id", nullable = false )
    private long accountId;

    @Column( name = "product_id", nullable = false )
    private long productId;

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn( name = "license_id", nullable = false )
    private License license;

etc.
```

where License is a joined entity with a String member licenseeName.

The JPA framework resolves this kind of interface methods auto-magically without the need to define the queries manually.